# "ps -aux" or "top" equivalent for Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, task-manager

I need to check which processes are running on a Windows Server instance, I'm looking for something similar to `top` or `ps -aux`, but I'm only finding references to use Task Manager with GUI.

What is the best way to check the running processes via command line in a Windows Server machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `tasklist`, available from Windows XP and 'til this day.